# SpecialStrings prob from topcoder srm 634 div 2

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I python seems work with not big length of input string, but it failed with pretty long string. Here is the problem statement:

A string S is called special if it satisfies the following two properties:
Each character in S is either '0' or '1'.
Whenever S = UV where both U and V are nonempty strings, U is strictly smaller than V in lexicographic order.
For example, the string S = "00101" is special because we have "0" < "0101", "00" < "101", "001" < "01", and "0010" < "1".
You are given a string current that is guaranteed to be special. Let N be the length of current. Consider the lexicographically sorted list of all special strings of length N. Compute and return the string that comes immediately after current in this list. If current happens to be the last string in the list, return an empty string instead.

Here is my python code:

```
class SpecialStrings(object):
    def findNext(self, current):
        if current == '0':
            return '1'
        N = len(current)
        iter_times = 2 ** N - int(current, 2) - 1
        temp_current = current
        for i in range(iter_times):
            temp_s = self.get_next_string(temp_current)
            if self.is_special(temp_s):
                return temp_s
            if temp_s[0] == '1':
                return ''
            temp_current = temp_s
        return ''

    def get_next_string(self, s):
        next_string = bin(int(s, 2) + 1)
        next_string = next_string[2:]
        if len(next_string) < len(s):
            temp_zero = '0' * (len(s) - len(next_string))
            next_string = temp_zero + next_string
        return next_string

    def is_special(self, s):
        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            left = s[:i]
            right = s[i:]
            if left >= right:
                return False
        return True
```

I received abnormal termination with inputs "0111111111111111111111111111" and "001111111111111111111111111111111111111111". When I tried to test it locally with either of them, my computer memory was exhausted......

What is the problem in here? Is it because my algorithm is not efficient? How to solve it?

Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: These are Lyndon words. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using Python2. In Py2, `range()` (your 8th line) returns a list. E.g. `range(3)` returns  [0, 1, 2]. So `range(iter_times)` creates a large list that use up memory. The simple workaround: use `xrange` instead. [Refer](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#xrange)

---

But with `xrange`, you may soon get another error:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Because the argument passed to xrange should not exceed max signed long. E.g. in my machine `xrange(0x7fffffff)` is OK, while `xrange(0x80000000)` can trigger the error. [Refer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)

Workaround: in your 8th line, use `while True:` instead. Because if the codes work as expected, the loop should anyway return result or empty string before hitting the end of for loop. So no need to use for loop.

---

The next trouble, when you use 'while True', input '0111111111111111111111111111' should work fine, but '001111111111111111111111111111111111111111' will keep calculating. That's the algorithm matter. You used brute force, long computation time is expected for large input. You may need to find pattern of special strings to improve the algorithm.

Comment: I considered about xrange at the beginning, but still got abnormal termination from topcoder system test, and ran out of memory when I tested locally. I trye While True but it costs about 10 minutes to get the result since it iterates over the while list. I think brute force is not realistic in here. Do you have any suggestion on algorithtm?